# How to add multiple web links on a button in c#?

Tags: c#, hyperlink

How to add multiple web links behind a single button in C#, so that web link always change whenever I click on the button and browser open next link on every click on the button?

Comment: Store different links in an string array. use a counter to save button click. based on the counter(as index to array) you can get the link from that array. then use that link for the current click.. repeat this logic.

Comment: @niksonkjohn brother i got your point but i want to give url value to web browser in visual studio,so how can i do it?how can i assign different values to browser's url property via string array?